# How to pass a variable to a different component in the same level with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am using Laravel 7 with Vue.js 2.

My view has the following code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div id="app">
        <report-meeting></report-meeting>
        <hr>
        <table-report></table-report>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

As you can see, there are two component at the same level. In the first component there is a form that when submitted should show a table that is located in the second component.

report-meeting:

```
        runReport: function() {
            axios.get('api/get_report', this.formReport)
            .then((response) => {
                this.errors = response.data;
                if (Object.keys(this.errors).length === 0) {
                    alert('viva');
                    this.success = false;
                    formReport = {};
                } else {
                    alert('vivano');
                    this.success = true;
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                alert('noviva');
                this.success = true;
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
```

table-report:

```
<template>
    <table class="table" v-bind:class="{invisible: success}">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>Lastname</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>john@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mary</td>
                <td>Moe</td>
                <td>mary@example.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>July</td>
                <td>Dooley</td>
                <td>july@example.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>   
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                success: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

My idea is to pass the variable `success` from the first component to the second one. When the form is submitted and passes the validation step the variable `success` should become `false` and so even the class `invisible` of the table should become `false` and the table will be visible.
Unfortunately I have no idea about how to connect the variable `success` between the two components.
Can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that when two sibling components need to 'communicate', a parent component should 'facilitate'. The report component may emit an event that will inform the parent, then the parent performs an action/sets a property to enable the table component to display.

In your case (laravel) the `parent component` is the Vue instance that's probably defined in resources/js/app.js (this Vue instance that targets''). I would not advice you to use this global instance for this page-specific functionality, because you probably have more pages. Instead you'd better create a new component that will be the parent and call this component in your page/blade.

Some snippets to clarify the possible solution:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div id="app">
        <reporter-app></reporter-app>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

```
// reporter-app.vue
<template>
   <div>
        <!-- listen for `success` events from report-meeting -->
        <report-meeting @success="displayTable=true"></report-meeting>
        <hr>
        <!-- only displays when displayTable == true -->
        <table-report v-if="displayTable"></table-report>
   </div>
   ....
</template>
```

```
// report-meeting.
runReport: function() {
            axios.get('api/get_report', this.formReport)
            .then((response) => {
               ...
               ...
               this.$emit('success')
            })
}
```

I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: Your third snippet doesn't work to me with the get method but it works only with post method... maybe you should change your axios call with "axios.get(url)" ? By the way, is it possible to do in a way that if the variable "success" is true the table is visible... and after that if the variable "success" will become false the table will return invisible? With your snippets the table will remain for good visible once appeared.

Comment: I based my snippets on what you have provided, to clarify how you can introduce this success signal to your code. By that same method you can add another signal, perhaps `this.$emit('failure')`, and to respond to this you would add '@failure="displayTable = false"` (in reporter-app.vue). The options are endless ;-)